# Using tblr with booktabs?

Tags: booktabs, tblr

Is it possible to use `tblr` with `booktabs`?

I seem to be getting error messages when I am trying to use it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tblr}{
                colspec = {ccc},
                row{2} = {purple7},
                column{3} = {teal7},
                cell{2}{3} = {yellow7},
            }
            \toprule
            First & Second & Third \\
            \toprule
            1 &  0 &  1 \\
            \midrule
            1 &  0 &  1 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

The error message is: `! Misplaced \noalign.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `\usepackage{booktabs}` with `\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}`:

[image: mwe]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But why is that needed?

Comment: From the manual: "The tabularray package **emulates or fixes some commands in other packages.** To avoid potential conflict, you need to enable them with \UseTblrLibrary command."